# Maximum Likelihood function using Sympy returns empty list

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, sympy, estimation

I wanted to create a function that would return estimator calculated by Maximum Likelihood Function. The function I made is below:

```
def Maximum_Likelihood(param, pmf):
    
    i = symbols('i', positive=True)
    n = symbols('n', positive=True)
    
    Likelihood_function = Product(pmf, (i, 1, n)) 
    # calculate partial derivative for parameter (p for Bernoulli)
    deriv = diff(Likelihood_function, param) 
    equation_to_solve = Eq(deriv,0) # equate with 0
    
    # solve above equation and return parameter (p for Bernoulli)
    return solve(equation_to_solve, param)
```

*Param* means parameter for which I want to know estimator and *pmf* is a probability mass function.

And for example, I want to get an estimator for parameter *p* in Bernoulli distribution.
How the Maximum Likelihood should look is:

[image: Maximum Likelihood]

My code.
Imports:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

from sympy.solvers import solve

from sympy import Product, Function, oo, IndexedBase, diff, Eq, symbols
```

Now, using Sympy I defined it:

```
def Maximum_Likelihood(param, pmf):
    
    i = symbols('i', positive=True)
    n = symbols('n', positive=True)
    
    Likelihood_function = Product(pmf, (i, 1, n)) 
    deriv = diff(Likelihood_function, param) 
    equation_to_solve = Eq(deriv,0) 
    
    return solve(equation_to_solve, param)
```

and Bernoulli example:

```
x = IndexedBase('x')
i = symbols('i', positive=True)
n = symbols('n', positive=True)
formula = (p**x[i])*((1-p)**(1-x[i]))

Likelihood_function = Product(formula, (i, 1, n))
Likelihood_function
```

When I want to get the outcome of Maximum_Likelihood(param, pmf):

```
param = p 
pmf = formula
print(Maximum_Likelihood(param, pmf))
```

I get "[]".
I want to obtain estimator of p that should look like:

[image: estimator of p]

Could you please take a look at it and advice what I do wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the diff of a product doesn't actually evaluate the derivative but you can use `doit` to force evaluation:

```
In [14]: solve(Eq(diff(Product(p**x[i]*(1 - p)**(1 - x[i]), (i, 1, n)), p), 0).doit(), p)
Out[14]: 
⎡  n       ⎤
⎢ ___      ⎥
⎢ ╲        ⎥
⎢  ╲       ⎥
⎢  ╱   x[i]⎥
⎢ ╱        ⎥
⎢ ‾‾‾      ⎥
⎢i = 1     ⎥
⎢──────────⎥
⎣    n     ⎦
```

That says that the MLE estimate for `p` is just the sample mean of the data I guess.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I was looking for.